# Search by Tags in SwashBuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swashbuckle

We are using SwashBuckle (5.6.0) in a .Net Framework 4.7.2.

we are using tags in all methods to group the API's , is any option to introuduce a search by tags inside the swagger.

Comment: Swagger schema uses JSON.  So you should be able to parse the schema with json methods.

Comment: Hi @jdweng any methods already in SwashBuckle for this ?

Comment: I do not know SwashBuckle.  You could use Net JSON.  I'm not realy a JSON expert so don't ask me.  Just know how to search for answers.

Comment: Can you provide some code of how your swagger json looks like, what about the version of the UI? Take a look at this one: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index there is a filter by tag is that what you need?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda, Yes i need some thing like this

Comment: <package id="Swashbuckle" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />
 <package id="Swashbuckle.Core" version="5.6.0" targetFramework="net452" />

Comment: The code for that is here: https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test

Comment: Thanks...Let me check